# Updgrade from .NET Framework 4.0 to 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks

I Have a solution with a lot of projects (WCFs, MVC 3, Console and Class Libraries).
I retarget the .Net Framework in all projects from 4.0 to 4.5 and build all without errors.

Except for having to install .NET Framework 4.5 on the server, do I need to check or to be worried with something else?

Is the process of retargeting the .Net Framework simple at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple in my experience - but there are some official [breaking changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (that have never impacted my upgrades)

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.5 is an "in-place upgrade" to .NET 4.0 so there *SHOULD* be no problems.

I highlight the "should" as there are some rare cases where it can make problems, but only testing your application will tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

You're more likely to have problems if upgrading from older versions like 2.0 or 3.5.

Comment: or 1.1. Which i had the pleasure of doing once